# How to convert BSTR to std::string in Visual Studio C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, api, visual-studio-2010, com

I am working on a COM dll. I wish to convert a BSTR to a std::string to pass to a method that takes a const reference parameter.

It seems that using _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString() to get the char* equivalent of the BSTR is an appropriate way to do so. However, the API documentation is sparse, and the implementation is potentially buggy:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewezf1f6(v=vs.100).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1969/BUG-in-_com_util-ConvertStringToBSTR-and-_com_util

Example:

```
#include <comutil.h>
#include <string>

void Example(const std::string& Str) {}

int main()
{
    BSTR BStr = SysAllocString("Test");
    char* CharStr = _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(BStr);
    if(CharStr != NULL)
    {
        std::string StdStr(CharStr);
        Example(StdStr);
        delete[] CharStr;
    }
    SysFreeString(BStr);
}
```

What are the pros and cons of alternatives to using ConvertBSTRToString(), preferrably based on standard methods and classes?

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out.  You can write your own converter with WideCharToMultiByte() and do something more reasonable when you get a one megabyte string.  Like throwing an exception.

Comment: To clarify, is this a question about a poorly documented MS comsupp-lib API? Or are you asking how to do this yourself? (or both?)

Comment: @WhozCraig: I suppose both, so perhaps I should split them into two separate questions, and I'll edit this one to focus on my goal rather than my method.

Comment: Note that, in that codeproject page, the author rants about a function allocating "twice as much memory as [it] needs," because they allocate `wcslen(str)*2`. There seems to be a misunderstanding as to just how wide wide-characters are. The article should be taken with some amount of salt, probably twice as much as usual.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this yourself. I prefer to convert into the target `std::string` if possible. If not, use a temp-value override.

```
// convert a BSTR to a std::string. 
std::string& BstrToStdString(const BSTR bstr, std::string& dst, int cp = CP_UTF8)
{
    if (!bstr)
    {
        // define NULL functionality. I just clear the target.
        dst.clear();
        return dst;
    }

    // request content length in single-chars through a terminating
    //  nullchar in the BSTR. note: BSTR's support imbedded nullchars,
    //  so this will only convert through the first nullchar.
    int res = WideCharToMultiByte(cp, 0, bstr, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (res > 0)
    {
        dst.resize(res);
        WideCharToMultiByte(cp, 0, bstr, -1, &dst[0], res, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {    // no content. clear target
        dst.clear();
    }
    return dst;
}

// conversion with temp.
std::string BstrToStdString(BSTR bstr, int cp = CP_UTF8)
{
    std::string str;
    BstrToStdString(bstr, str, cp);
    return str;
}
```

Invoke as:

```
BSTR bstr = SysAllocString(L"Test Data String")
std::string str;

// convert directly into str-allocated buffer.
BstrToStdString(bstr, str);

// or by-temp-val conversion
std::string str2 = BstrToStdString(bstr);

// release BSTR when finished
SysFreeString(bstr);
```

Something like that, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is exactly what I need for my situation. Out of curiosity (and the hope to improve my programming through understanding others' code), and if it's appropriate to ask, what is the reason for having the return reference as well as having the output reference parameter?

Comment: Of course, now that I've engaged my brain, it allows the method to be used in line with the method call (`Example(BstrToStdString(AString))` in my example). This convenience seems to be traded off with the risk that using a temporary as the 'dst' input (e.g. `BstrToStdString(bstr,"")`) could result in an invalid reference being returned.

Comment: @user1472525 the latter example in your comment, `BstrToStdString(bstr,"")`, is not valid, as the input parameter would have to be of type `const std::string&` and it is not for what is hopefully an obvious reason (it is, after all, the target of the conversion). So you should be ok regardless. I often pass such a parameter by *address* rather than reference so as to clarify the out-param-ness of its state, but doing such *really* raises the hackles of most hard-core C++ folk =P

Comment: WhozCraig*: Thanks for the clarification, I hadn't considered the `const` nature of `""`. Also, thanks for avoiding a pointer/reference debate, SO has enough of those already :-).

* The `@` functionality doesn't seem to be working this time...

Comment: It's should be `dst.resize(res - 1);` cause std::string size doesn't count null terminated character

Answer (score -1):

Easy way

BSTR => CStringW => CW2A => std::string.

Comment: The [`CW2A` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(v=vs.80).aspx) recommends using `COLE2CA` instead, which would skip the `CStringW`.