# How to pass BSTR to printf?

Tags: c++, printf, bstr

I have a non-unicode (MBCS) C++ project building with VS2013.

Given a `BSTR` value, how should I pass this to printf safely?

Comment: Did you search?  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725519/how-to-convert-bstr-to-stdstring-in-visual-studio-c-2010) will get you most of the way there...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert BSTR to char\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648848/convert-bstr-to-char).

Comment: Not a duplicate. `printf` can print `wchar_t` so there's no point in the conversion.

Comment: Just use the %ls format specifier.

Comment: I did search and found no direct duplicate, or direct answer on other sites - which I found very surprising. I wondered if `_bstr_t` is the answer, as it so often is with BSTR?

Answer (score 10):

A `BSTR` really is a `WCHAR*` with preceding length information. You can ignore that length part for printing purposes. So:

```
BSTR str = foo();
printf("%S", str); // Capital S
```

Comment: Can you point out the documentation for the capital S printf specifier? It doesn't appear to be standard C.

Comment: @user2079303 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx - this is MSDN so it _is_ Microsoft-specific - the link says so.

Comment: I figured that with `BSTR` being Microsoft-specific this isn't an issue. `%ls` is portable.

Comment: You can also use `wprintf()`

Answer (score 1):

A `BSTR` is a pointer to a length-prefixed (at offset -4) and `0`-terminated wide-character string. You can pass it to any function that is capable of handling a `0`-terminated wide-character string. (The actual string starts at offset `0`.)

If the target function cannot handle wide characters, then you need to convert the string to multibyte characters (this is the case if you want to use standard `printf` where the `S` type field character is not available). This (already commented) link provides information about that: [Convert BSTR to char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648848/convert-bstr-to-char)

@MSalters' answer has the code example (don't want to duplicate 2 trivial lines): https://stackoverflow.com/a/32482688/682404